# VBA compare multiple cells on multiple sheets

Tags: vba, comparison

I need some help with comparing multiple cells on multiple sheets and deleting duplicates.  If Column A and B on Sheet1 match Column A and B on Sheet2 then I need to delete that row.

Please help.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5lM2.png)

In the above sample I need to delete Row 2 and Row 4 from Sheet2.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub DeleteDuplicatesOnSheets()

   Dim Ws As Worksheet
   Dim Cl As Range
   Dim ValU As String
   Dim Qty As Long
   Dim Rng As Range

   For Each Ws In Worksheets

   On Error Resume Next

      With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
         For Each Cl In Ws.Range("C2", Ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            ValU = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Cl.Resize(, 4))))
            If Not .exists(ValU) Then
               .Add ValU, Nothing
            Else
               Qty = Qty + 1
               If Rng Is Nothing Then
                  Set Rng = Cl
               Else
                  Set Rng = Union(Rng, Cl)
               End If
            End If
         Next Cl
         If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.EntireRow.Delete
         .RemoveAll
      End With
   Next Ws
   MsgBox Qty & " rows have been deleted"

End Sub
```